# Want interval to test for exact time match

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an interval that runs every 3 seconds to check for new data. If it finds new data it broadcasts a dataChange event and my item renderer is updated.

I need to test a comparison for when two times match exactly...for one time only. Meaning, the data comes back is a meeting. The meeting starts at 3pm. When the match is run, the meeting turns blue and users can enter.

I broadcast a dataChange event for when the compared times match but I don't want to keep broadcasting it over and over, i.e.

```
private static const NOW_OFFSET_TIME:Number = 1000 * 60 * 15;

    private function shouldShowNow(start:Date, end:Date):Boolean
    {
        var now:Date = new Date;

        var stime:Number = start.time - NOW_OFFSET_TIME;
        var etime:Number = end.time;

        return ((now.time >= stime) && (now.time <= etime));
    }
```

In the code above, the condition will always return true once

```
now.time >= stime
```

...and the dataChange event gets run over and over and over.

But my interval runs only 3 seconds so it won't trap an exact match. Heck, I even switched my interval to every 500 ms and it won't trap it.

What are my other options?

Thanks for any helpful input.

UPDATE: I could do this (but I'd have to run my interval every second):

```
private static const NOW_OFFSET_TIME:Number = 1000 * 60 * 15;

    private function shouldShowNow(start:Date, end:Date):Boolean
    {
        var now:Date = new Date;
        var match:Boolean;

        if( now.hours == start.hours && now.minutes == ( start.minutes - 15 ) && now.seconds == start.seconds ){
            match = true;
        }else{
            match = false;
        }

        return match;
    }
```

And here is the handler for the interval in full:

```
/*
                            We want to compare the current upcomingCalendarList collection 
                            against the collection returned; if they are different, update the UI.
                        */
                        var meetingsData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
                        meetingsData = getArrayCollectionFromXML( event.result.response.participantMeetingList.meeting );

                        var cachedColl:ArrayCollection = com.fmr.transporter.model.GeneralInfoModel.getInstance().upcomingMeetingList;
                        var returnedColl:ArrayCollection = meetingsData;
                        var updates:Boolean = false; // our flag to let us know if there are changes in the meeting list

                        if( returnedColl != null )
                        {
                            // Meetings have been added/removed
                            if( cachedColl.length != returnedColl.length ){
                                updates = true;
                            }
                            // Look for meeting  updates
                            else
                            {
                                for( var i:int=0;i<cachedColl.length;i++ ){
                                    var currMeeting:MeetingVO = cachedColl[i] as MeetingVO;

                                    for( var j:int=0;j<returnedColl.length;j++ ){
                                        var returnedMtg:ObjectProxy = returnedColl[j];
                                        /*
                                            We want to ensure we're comparing the same meeting (meetingID) for
                                            any changes.
                                        */
                                        if( currMeeting.meetingID == returnedMtg.meetingId )
                                        {
                                            var startTime_GMT:Date = converServerUTCTimeStampToLocalDate( returnedMtg.startTime );
                                            var endTime_GMT:Date = converServerUTCTimeStampToLocalDate( returnedMtg.endTime );

                                            if( ObjectUtil.dateCompare( currMeeting.startTime, startTime_GMT ) != 0 )
                                                updates = true;
                                            else if( ObjectUtil.dateCompare( currMeeting.endTime, endTime_GMT ) != 0 )
                                                updates = true;
                                            else if( currMeeting.meetingName != returnedMtg.meetingName )
                                                updates = true;
                                            else if( this.shouldShowNow( startTime_GMT, endTime_GMT ) )
                                                updates = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            // If there are no updates, leave the cached collections alone. 
                            if( !updates ){
                                return;
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: If you let Flash Builder make your setters for you and check the "dispatch custom event" boxes, then FB will add code that only allows the internals of the setter to run if the value has changed, and not at any other time. I can't be bothered looking through all that code, but if you're not using a setter you can adapt the idea.

Comment: Hi Amy, thanks for responding. I've read your blog before and it's been very helpful. Can you elaborate on your response, please? What piece should be set via a setter?

Comment: Probably whatever property you're using on the data object that's feeding the meeting View that lets it know that it should turn blue. You can set that property as many times as you want, but only if it changes will it dispatch a change event.  If you don't have a separate data object driving your View, that's probably the crux of your architectural flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it would be best for you to add a property to your MeetingVO class to track whether you've shown it already.  something like `public var hasBeenShown:Boolean = false`

Then, in you else if where you call shouldShowNow, update it to this:

```
else if (!currMeeting.hasBeenShown && this.shouldShowNow(startTime_GMT, endTime_GMT, currMeeting))
```

Then in your shouldshowNow function, update it to this:

```
private function shouldShowNow(start:Date, end:Date, meeting:MeetingVO):Boolean
{
    var now:Date = new Date;

    var stime:Number = start.time - NOW_OFFSET_TIME;
    var etime:Number = end.time;

    if((now.time >= stime) && (now.time <= etime)){
        meeting.hasBeenShown = true;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I can't because the interval runs continuously to check for other things besides a meeting starting, i.e. new meetings added/canceled, etc...

Comment: Ah, well then you have a bit of a design flaw.  If you show more code - like what calls shouldShowNow - then I can give you some tips.  You'll need to have a flag somewhere to tell if your meeting has been updated already.

Comment: I updated my original post with 1 solution. It's not great but it'll do. But I agree, I think there is a design flaw. The handler for the interval compares two collections; the cached collection on the client and the returned collection. If the collections are different lengths, I know there is a new/deleted meeting. If the start time of a meeting is now, I have to update the collection, etc...I'll add more code now.

Comment: That's definately not the way you're going to want to do that. There is no guarantee that it will work 100% of the time because even though you set you interval to 1 second, the slightest performance hiccup could make it a few milliseconds off causing your function to never return true. Plus what if the user runs the software after the first second that is applicable here?    Show your code that calls shouldShowNow() and maybe there will be an easy solution for you

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'm going to adapt my code to work with your solution.